# What can a web app do with my Twitter account if I use Twitter to login to that service?

Tags: twitter, security, login, oauth

When I use a Twitter account to login to another website, **what does that authorize that website to do with my Twitter account?**

Does it enable them to send tweets from my account, or send direct messages, or anything else that someone might find unwanted?

Answer (score 3):

Twitter auth has two levels, read and read write. You are told the level they want before you authorise the website. With write they can do pretty much anything they like, however you can deauthenticate them in twitter, so itisn't in the sites beat interest.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that - you need to look pretty closely at the messages to know what you are letting the app do though.
Can you deauthenticate a site from read+write to read only? Or do you have to completely remove access for that site.

Comment: Twitter only seems to have a "deauthorize" option. I wish they allowed users to grant and revoke specific permissions. That's something at which Facebook Platform is halfway decent.